# How to hide <td>s in angularjs in particular rows when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table and and many `<td>`s in first `<tr>` `</tr>` i am using **ng-repeat**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="receipt in $data">
   <td   data-title="voucher number">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_no}}</span> 
   </td>
    <td   data-title="voucher date" sortable="'voucher_date'" filter="{'voucher_date': 'text' }">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_date}}</span> 
   </td>
    <td   data-title="voucher Amount">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_amount}}</span> 
   </td> 
  </tr>
```

i have also json data like

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "voucher_no": "2",
            "voucher_amount": "100",
            "voucher_date": "2014-05-04",
      },
        {
            "voucher_no": "3",
            "voucher_amount": "1000000",
            "voucher_date": "2014-02-05",
        },
        {
            "voucher_no": "4",
            "voucher_amount": "50000",
            "voucher_date": "2014-02-05",
        },
        .
        .
        .
        .
        {
            "total": 1360100
        }
    ]
}

please note that for final data there is only one field 'total'.
```

so  for  all the  row i want to print 3 `<td>`s  except the in final row.

Comment: What do you want that filter to do? At the moment it will show only the voucher_date columns which contain the word 'text'.

Comment: i want all td from a particular date. i donno am using the propr way

Comment: Well using the filter property on the td will only hide that td. I guess you need to hide the entire row if the date is not valid. I've updated my answer with a valid filter for this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="receipt in $data | filter:{voucher_date: '2014-05-04'}">
    <!-- Voucher No -->
    <td ng-if="!$last"
        data-title="voucher number">
        <span>{{receipt.voucher_no}}</span> 
    </td>

    <!-- Voucher Date -->
    <td ng-if="!$last"
        data-title="voucher date">
         <span>{{receipt.voucher_date}}</span> 
    </td>

    <!-- Voucher Amount -->
    <td ng-if="!$last"
        data-title="voucher Amount">
        <span>{{receipt.voucher_amount}}</span> 
    </td>

    <!-- Total Column -->
    <td ng-if="$last"
        colspan="3"
        data-title="Total">
        <span>{{receipt.total}}</span> 
    </td>
</tr>
```

The above filter will only show the records for which the date is equal to the specified date.

If you want to show all the records between two dates you will need to specify a function as the filter: `| filter:filter_between_date` and in your controller you have to create that function:

```
$scope.from_date = '2014-05-04'; // 04 May
$scope.to_date = '2014-05-10'; // 10 May
$scope.filter_between_date = function(item) {
    var item_date = new Date(item.voucher_date).getTime();

    if(item_date >= (new Date($scope.from_date).getTime()) &&
        item_date <= (new Date($scope.to_date).getTime()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};
```

[Angular filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

[Angular ngIf directive docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

[Angular ngRepeat $last property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: it works but but i have to filter the <td> .when i am filtering that is missing <td sortable="'voucher_date'" filter="{ 'voucher_date': 'text' } >.... </td>

Comment: Could you please update your question so that it also contains details about this filter?!

Comment: Please have in mind there is a difference between ng-if and ng-hide:
["The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)
["The ngHide directive shows or hides the given HTML element"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

In the first case, the DOM element is actually removed, while in the second case, that element is present but hidden with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
  <tr ng-repeat="receipt in $data">
   <td   data-title="voucher number" ng-hide="$index == $data.length - 1">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_no}}</span> 
   </td>
    <td   data-title="voucher date" ng-hide="$index == $data.length - 1">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_date}}</span> 
   </td>
    <td   data-title="voucher Amount">
    <span>{{receipt.voucher_amount}}</span> 
   </td> 
  </tr>
```

The $index variable stores the position of the repeated element in the original list.

Comment: You can use ng-repeats $last variable instead of comparing index to data.length: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks mer10z_tech, I didn't know that one !

Comment: is $last variable holds the last field of the  row or last row?

Comment: $last is "true if the repeated element is last in the iterator." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat